# How to let React select component so extend its parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I'm using react-select for a drop down menu looking like this

[image: Dropdown picture]

component looks like this :

```
<table className="w-full text-sm text-center  text-projectlightblack  overflow-hidden  font-poppins my-10 border-t border-t-projectblue border-l border-l-projectblue ">
      <thead className="text-xl bg-projectbackgroundgray   text-projectlightblack font-medium"></thead>
      <tbody className="font-normal text-lg whitespace-pre-line text-start px-[10px] ">
        {data?.rows?.map((row, index) => {
          return (
            <tr
              className="py-[10px] border-b border-b-projectblue border-r border-r-projectblue border-t-0 border-l-0"
              key={index}
            >
              {row?.map((cell, index) => {
                let {
                  value,
                  tailwindClasses,
                  cellType,
                  dataType,
                  address,
                  options,
                } = processCell(cell, cellData) || {};

                if (cellType == "input" && dataType == "list") {
                  return (
                    <td className="w-[300px] h-auto" key={index}>
                      {isLoading || isFetching ? (
                        <InputLoadingIndicator />
                      ) : (
                        <Select
                          options={options}
                          isLoading={isLoading || isFetching}
                          value={value}
                          onChange={(option) => {
                            setQueryKey(option);
                            mutate({
                              addressValue: address,
                              dateValue: option.value,
                            });
                          }}
                          styles={{
                            control: (baseStyles, state) => ({
                              ...baseStyles,
                              borderColor: state.isFocused ? "white" : "white",
                            }),
                          }}
                          menuPlacement="auto"
                        />
                      )}
                    </td>
                  );
                }
```

basically when I extend the dropdown menu and it's bigger than parent component it doesn't work , giving a fixed height to the table tag would fix it but it's a reusable component and that's ruin it , Any other fixes?

Comment: The obvious solution here is to remove the `overflow-hidden` class from your `<table>`. What is the reason to use `overflow-hidden` on the table to start with?

Comment: @3limin4t0r omg , that fixes it , I had it because I had borders on the table and that made it work , Can you explain to me why overflow hidden makes it not possible ?

Comment: You can find the basic documentation regarding CSS `overflow` [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow). The reason you should hide overflow in this scenario is simply because `react-div` is simply an HTML structure with CSS styling and interactive behaviour that can flows outside of the parent element if its height or with is too small. The CSS `overflow: hidden` does the same with styled components as it does with text. Everything flowing outside of the element is hidden, that's why the `<Select>` options are partially shown.